# System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: 'SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999

Tags: asp.net

My data access layer:

```cs
public void InsertStaffInfo(StaffInformationModel staff)
{
    try
    {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        db.MyConn();
        SqlCommand insertstaffinfo = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertUpdateDeleteStaffInfo", db.con);
        insertstaffinfo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_ID", 0);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_FNAME", staff.STAFF_FNAME);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_MNAME", staff.STAFF_MNAME);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_LNAME", staff.STAFF_LNAME);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_GENDER", staff.STAFF_GENDER);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_DOB", staff.STAFF_DOB);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_AGE", staff.STAFF_AGE);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_OCCUPATION",staff.STAFF_OCCUPATION);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_QUALIFICATION", staff.STAFF_QUALIFICATION);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_DOJ", staff.STAFF_DOJ);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAFF_IMAGE", staff.STAFF_IMAGE);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMG_PATH", staff.IMAGE_PATH);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATED_BY", staff.CREATED_BY);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATED_ON", staff.CREATED_ON);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS_ACTIVE", staff.IS_ACTIVE);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS_DELETE", staff.IS_DELETE);
        insertstaffinfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODE", 'I');
        insertstaffinfo.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string errorMsg = "";
        errorMsg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(errorMsg);
    }
}

insertstaff.STAFF_DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdob.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and try to [edit] your question, so it contains your actual question. Where exactly are you facing your error?

Comment: Is one of your dates maybe `DateTime.MinValue` (=0001-01-01)?